# Converting line chart into bar graph

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I have made a Jasper line chart using ireport. Now I want to convert this line chart into bar graph. Keeping everything same (parameters, fields and data) is there a way or even possible to convert it into bar chart seamlessly (with minimal effort)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to convert one chart to a different type of chart.  At least not in version 3.5.2.  Right click on the chart and see if there is a "Transform In" option (for some controls you can do this).  I'm guessing there is not.

If there is not, I would take screen shots of all of the settings for your current graph.  Then create a new bar graph and fill in the settings as they were for the line graph.

Hopefully this helps.